# LocalNetworkGatewayCannotHaveEmptyAddressPrefixAndBgpSettings Error when setting up local network gateway

Tags: azure-active-directory, vpn, local-network

Trying to setup a local network gateway and hitting this error:

> LocalNetworkGatewayCannotHaveEmptyAddressPrefixAndBgpSettingsThe local network gateway /subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/XXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Network/localNetworkGateways/XXXXX cannot have both empty address prefix and empty BGP Settings.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7WPy.jpg)]

All the XX are just obfuscations of my org's specifics.
I'm not seeing a place wwhere i can set the address prefix, and I'm not setting up BGP. Not sure where to look next.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to create local network gateway I got the same error below:

```
LocalNetworkGatewayCannotHaveEmptyAddressPrefixAndBgpSettingsThe local network gateway /subscriptions/b83cxxxxxf/resourceGroups/imran-/providers/Microsoft.Network/localNetworkGateways/LNG1 cannot have both empty address prefix and empty BGP Settings.
```

[image]

This error usually occurs when the address space is set to `None`. No address space details or BGP settings are configured.

Make sure to add address space like below:

[image]

Now I am able to successfully create a local network gateway like below:

[image]

To view BGP setting while creating in advance tab you can see or once deployed, under configuration you can set shown below:

[image]

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!